# Upload file to server using Http

Tags: php, android, file-upload

I amm trying to upload couple of audio files to server using the following method, and server side code is written in php. My concern is that out of three files two are being uploaded, but one files is not uploading to server. I have checked the that the path of file is correct and removed white spaces from the path. Still can't figure out why one of these files is not uploading.

here is the code

```
int serverResponseCode = 0;

      HttpURLConnection connection;
      DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary = "*****";


      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
      File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);


      String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
      final String fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

      try {
          // Log.e("selected file", selectedFile.toString());
          Log.e("selected file path ", selectedFilePath);
          FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
          URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
          connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
          connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
          connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
          connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
          System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
          connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
          //connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
          connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
          connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
          connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", selectedFilePath);

          //creating new dataoutputstream
          dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

          //writing bytes to data outputstream
          dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
          dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                  + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

          dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

          //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
          bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
          //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
          bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
          //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
          buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

          bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

          //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
          while (bytesRead > 0) {

              //write the bytes read from inputstream
              dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
              bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
              bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
              bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

          }

          dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

          dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
          serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
          String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

          Log.e("TAG", "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

          //closing the input and output streams

          Log.e("above closing ", " fileinputstreamclosing");
          fileInputStream.close();
          dataOutputStream.flush();
          dataOutputStream.close();


      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();

          {
              Log.e("File Not Found", "");
          }

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();


      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();

      }
```

And to be exact about the path these are the filepaths -

1 - /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Audio/AUD-20160322-WA0009.mp3, 2-/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Audio/AUD-20160728-WA0002.mp3

these two are able to uplaod to server but

/storage/emulated/0/Download/Shawn%20Mendes%20-%20Treat%20You%20Better.mp3 
this can't .. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

php code

```
<?php

$file_path = "uploads/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

?>

Edit

```
  @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {


           for ( i = 0; i < selectedsongpath.size(); i++) {
               Log.e("doinback", "doinback" + "    " + i);

             String finalstring =  selectedsongpath.get(i).replace(" ", "%20");
               Log.e("removing space ", finalstring);
               uploadFile(finalstring);
               //  doFileUpload(removingSpace);
              // Log.e("for loop" , currentPhonePath + "    " +  currentSongTitle);
           }
```

Uploadfile is the method which i posted earlier

Comment: Maybe an upload size limit issue on the server side...can you post the size for each file?...also the http server that you are using(nginx, apache, etc)

Comment: server side code is very basic or i say simple its just put the file in the uploads folder. I will make the edit right now. And size is definitely not 0 as i can play that audio in my device.

Comment: But the file size for each file?...also the webserver that you are using?

Comment: am using linux hosting as a webserver got apache integrated with hosting and what do you mean  by file size ?

Comment: The size for each mp3 file...for example apache maybe is limiting the upload size to 4 mb...so if you try to upload a file > to 4 mb then the upload files....I think that your issue is related to this

Comment: no thats not the issue i guess because all files are in range of 3.20MB to 3.50MB. /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Audio/AUD-20160322-WA0009.mp3 this file is of largest size of 3.46MB to be exact. while the file which is not being uploaded is of size 3.28MB.

Comment: Then you can do the following, replace your $file_path line with those two lines: `$filename =  str_replace('%20', '_', $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']); $file_path = $file_path.basename($filename);`

Comment: You are uploading only one file so your cmplaint does not make sense.

Comment: @Hackerman it doesnt work buddy :/  And to greenapps am uploading three files, only one file doesnt upload to server out of three

Comment: You are uploading 3 files, but in the code you are showing us just how you upload one file...I think that is what greenapps is referring

Comment: Hackermans idea was ok. But you should replace %20 by a space BEFORE uploading. Before you use it to open a FileInputStream. You will have an Exception clearly visible in the logcat. Most of your catch blocks are empty so you dont know.

Comment: Moreover you did not inform us about response codes. Or response messages. But the biggest problem with your code is that you do not read the echos() from php. So you do not know if "fail" or "succes" is returned.

Comment: Firstly, i only added the that part of code where the problem is arising, am uploading those file in a loop, fetching there path from ArrayList, In two files the response code is 200,  and the third one there is no response code nor any exception nor crash. Moreover am replacing %20 before for-loop there is no problem in that. So, if you want whole code i will edit, but that will be of no use as that code doesnt have anything major.

Comment: You should have three times a response code of course. If you dont have three responses something goes terrible wrong. If you cannot find out yourself then yes show your loop.

Comment: Please see the Edit @greenapps

Comment: Do a test where you upload the third file first. Put every where more log statements so you better see how the code flows. Please also show complete uploadFile() function. Let uploadFile return a String with a message. Collect those strings in the loop so you can display the collected strings in onPostExecute().

Comment: You should only request response code and message AFTER you closed the data output stream.

Comment: Do a test where you only upload the third file.

Comment: `String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
      final String fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];`. Terrible code. Better:`String fileName = selectedFile.getName();`.